# How to add In app Purchasing to apps for Opera Mobile Store

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, opera, in-app-billing

I'm trying to figure out how to use Opera's Mobile Store with my Android app. There's barely any documentation. Does anyone know how in app purchasing API works for communicating with Opera's Mobile Store?  Is there even such a functionality. Opera's dev website doesn't provide any API.

Or would you suggest a 3rd party plugin / payment system that I can use?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thank you for your message.
Currently we don't offer in-app payments, but this might change in the following year.

What you can do as of now is to integrate any 3-d party in-app payment solution and submit such apps to Opera Mobile Store.
This could be SMS payments from providers like Boku, Zong, iFree, MoPay, etc or in-app payments via PayPal, Google Checkout, etc.

With best regards,
Victor Shaburov - apps.opera.com